# How to change automatically assigned DateTime2 data type to DateTime with EF Core, Code First?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I am writing a new application with ASP.NET Core 2.2.4 with EF Core Code First approach with migrations. I wrote my domain models and updated the database via Package Manager Console but this resulted in all the DateTime properties I have throughout my domain models to be created as DateTime2(7) table columns.
I need only DateTime.

First I tried to change this by writing a query in SQL server to change the data type and it did, inside SQL Server it's showing that it's changed to datetime. But when I open SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio it still shows the column as a datetime2(7) type.

After that I tried adding the following annotation to the DateTime properties
[Column(TypeName = "DateTime")]. I added a migration after that and updated the db via Package Manager Console. This didn't have any effect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GYM.CoreApp.WebUI.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100), MinLength(2)]
        [Display(Name ="First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100), MinLength(2)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "DateTime")]
        [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(13), MinLength(13)]
        [Display(Name = "EMBG")]
        public string EMBG { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200), MinLength(2)]
        [Display(Name = "Home address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(13), MinLength(9)]
        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Salary per month")]
        public int SalaryPerMonth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "DateTime")]
        [Display(Name = "Date when joined company")]
        public DateTime DateWhenJoined { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Still Employed")]
        public bool StillEmployed { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: `[Column(TypeName = "DateTime")]` should do the trick, you probably saw some cached database info. That said, I'd prefer the columns to have type `Date`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer doesn't provide a how to force EF Core to create a column with `datetime` instead of `datetime2` because you shouldn't.

The main difference between SQL server `datetime2` and `datetime` is the precision and wider date range that can be utilized.  The default will be `datetime2` for a `System.DateTime` and there isn't a reason not to use it when you are using a compatible client.

`System.DateTime` maps directly to SQL Server `datetime2` and is the Microsoft recommended datatype for storage of a `System.DateTime` in SQL Server.

Also worth noting that a `datetime2(7)` takes one less byte of space than a `datetime` and offers increased precision.

See the Note on [MSDN SQL Server datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: That is good to know. However, I'm going from a user point of view. No user would be okay with filling in the whole datetime format. How would you execute this?

Comment: Please post a code example of what you mean by user filling out the "whole datetime format".  Within your C# code there is no difference between the interactions of System.DateTime in order to store in SQL server as a datetime2.

Comment: @Shepherd the User Interface is (or at least should be) completely separate from the underlying storage mechanism. And as noted in this answer, the .net storage is the same regardless, so the UI will never know.

Comment: I mean by having an input field such as: 
<input type="date" name="bday">

Comment: The default for pretty much any programming language I can think of will be to set the time portion to 00:00:00 if it isn't explicitly declared.  var date = new DateTime(2019, 5, 7);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString()); results in 5/7/2019 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Your `input` display is unrelated to your database storage type. Its displaying like that because you've chosen a `date` input type. Use a date/time picker and forget the storage mechanism.

Comment: Very well, I'll leave it as is: datetime2.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. Then use the `TypeName` attribute:

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
```

If SQL Server Object Explorer is still showing datetime2, you may need to exit and re-open Visual Studio.

Comment: It is installed. It's 2.2 version. Does it make a difference if the string is "datetime" or "DateTime"?

Comment: not sure. try it! also, if your database is now correctly using datetime, and it's just Visual Studio that is giving you problems, try closing and opening Visual Studio

Comment: Still creating datetime2(7)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add **datetime** type on the column in the migration like:

```
CreatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false, type: "datetime")
```